# Unable to Connect to any Servers Error on Cassandra Seed Host

Tags: cassandra

In my Cassandra 3-node setup, all the seed nodes are working fine. However, I am unable to connect to the seed host.

I get the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': 
  error(111,"Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: *As you haven't specified which version of Cassandra you are running, or how you are attempting to connect to your cluster (cqlsh, Java client driver, etc...) I am going to make some assumptions here.  For the future, that's good information to provide.*

My guess is that if you were to run a `nodetool status` from one of your nodes, that you wouldn't see "127.0.0.1" in the list.  Example:

```
$ nodetool status | grep 192.168 | awk '{ print $2 }'
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

My point, is that even if I am on 192.168.1.1, `cqlsh 127.0.0.1` or `cqlsh` (without the IP) won't work.  I **need to specify the (non-localhost) IP address**, which is probably going to be the value of your `listen_address` or `rpc_address`.